# Cannot install Stripe.net on PCL side in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, stripe.net

I am working with Xamarin (Android, iOS, UWP). Stripe is my last thing to integrate, however, I can't find the way to install it in the PCL part. I could install it for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS.

The error thrown from the PCL part at the NuGet installation is the following:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Stripe.net.10.4.0' with respect to project 'PROJECT', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/stripe.net/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/stripe.net/index.json 289ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/stripe.net/page/7.7.0/10.4.0.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/stripe.net/page/7.7.0/10.4.0.json 531ms
Total number of results gathered : 20
Gathering dependency information took 826.02 ms
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -   825.53 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Stripe.net.10.4.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Stripe.net.10.4.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Stripe.net.10.4.0'
Found package 'Stripe.net 10.4.0' in '/xxx/PROJECT/packages'.
For adding package 'Stripe.net.10.4.0' to project 'PROJECT' that targets 'portable45-net45+win8+wpa81'.
Install failed.Rolling back...
Package 'Stripe.net.10.4.0' does not exist in project 'PROJECT'
Executing nuget actions took 46.19 ms
Could not install package 'Stripe.net 10.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I tried to change the profile to 259 without success... There is my packages :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="PCLCrypto" version="2.0.147" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="PCLStorage" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="PInvoke.BCrypt" version="0.5.97" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="PInvoke.Kernel32" version="0.5.97" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="PInvoke.NCrypt" version="0.5.97" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="PInvoke.Windows.Core" version="0.5.97" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Plugin.Permissions" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Validation" version="2.4.15" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="3.0.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Geolocator" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.PushNotification" version="1.2.4" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Auth" version="1.5.0.3" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.270" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" version="2.3.4.270" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

I have [reported this issue to Stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/999).

Comment: Convert your PCL to NetStd 1.5 and you can add the Stripe package, if you are unable to convert from P111 to NetStd at this time you can use a dependency service to access Stripe in your application projects...

Comment: How do you achieve that? I'm sorry but I never did it before :/

Comment: Are you using VS or VS4M?

Comment: I'm on a MacBook Pro

Comment: Open your library (PCL) project options and on the build / general page, change the target to `.Net Standard Platform: netstandard1.5`. Backup/commit any changes **before** doing this, afterward check your packages/references for any that are broken and/or need re-targeted. Then do a clean build and thoroughly test your app.

Comment: Some packages like `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` aren't compatibles :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153399/discussion-between-emixam23-and-sushihangover).